# TFS - error when trying to add "Windows user or group" to licensed users - adding group

Tags: tfs

I have: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer Version 9.0.21022.8

When I go to Team->Team Foundation Server Settings->Group Memberships;

Double-click on 'Team Foundation Server Licensed Users';

Select "Windows User or Group" in the 'Add Member';
In the "Select Users, Computers or Groups" type in the group name, then 'Check Names', resolved, press 'OK'.

Now I can see the group added to the 'User or Group' list.

Unfortunately, when I press 'OK' I get the following unhelpful message

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Team Foundation Error

### MyGroup

### OK   Help

(where 'MyGroup' is the name of the Windows group I was trying to add).

At the same time, though, adding individual users from that group works fine.

Any ideas on where to begin with this error (pressing 'Help' shows the 'Information not Found' page).

Comment: Get a little more clear now, when addind users one by one got to 

TF50626: Maximum users (5) in License group. Unable to add 'FirstName LastName'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rwmnau said, the WGE is limited to five. If you purchase a new license you can 'Repair' the app and it'll offer you a place to add the new license code - so you don't need to un-install/ re-install.

Answer (score 1):

The workgroup edition has a limitation of five users, so it doesn't allow you to add groups in the security manager. If you could add groups, you could potentially add more than five users, and then it wouldn't know which five to give access to. I would suspect that this is your problem, though I would expect a more helpful error message - maybe something along the lines of "Unable to add a Group in this TFS edition", or something like that.

EDIT: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404880.aspx) explains the process, and notes that you can't add groups to the workgroup edition - only individual users.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it appears that we have a 'limited version' which I was not informed of, and can see no indication of ... anyway, that seems to be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a couple of my own findings:

- The issue was, as suggested, the 'Workgroup edition'
- The 'Repair' option is a bit tricky, as explained here
  [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/2a13ec88-e199-48e6-8312-de9602cf7577/][1]
  (involves manually editing the setup.sdb file)
- Even after upgrade, there is a limitation on 5 users for that particular 'Licenced Users' group.
  As I understood from here
  [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/21eb519c-7871-4e4b-ade8-3614b3a1d2a3/][2]
  I am not supposed to use the 'Licensed Users' group at all in full version, but rahter use project groups. Seems to work fine for me.

  [1]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/2a13ec88-e199-48e6-8312-de9602cf7577/"Upgrading TFS 2008 Workgroup to Std. Edition"
  [2]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/21eb519c-7871-4e4b-ade8-3614b3a1d2a3/"Upgrading from limited version"

Comment: Gosh, what did I do to the URL's ... =)